# Permission denied to to transfer files from remote server

Tags: ssh

Dear ubuntu community when i  Copy the file from remote server (After login in to server from my Home computer) using scp commands as follows

```
scp -v CNTPEPRSOLIONSfullcputest.log  root@127.0.0.1:~/
```

it asks the password of root Though i. I supply it doesn't accept it for 3 times and then I get `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password)`

My verbose output I posted for you kind help

How to solve the problems?

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 127.0.0.1, user root, command scp -v -t ~/
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/vidhyasankar1685/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vidhyasankar1685/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vidhyasankar1685/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '127.0.0.1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/vidhyasankar1685/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vidhyasankar1685/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vidhyasankar1685/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vidhyasankar1685/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@127.0.0.1's password:
```

Comment: Your copying files FROM your REMOTE server but the address is 127.0.0.1 ?

It should be formatted scp YOURREMOTESERVERLOGIN@YOURREMOTESERVERADDRESS:/remote/file/location /local/file/location

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying files **from** your **remote** server

Then why is the address you specify **local** 127.0.0.1

When entered from your **local** prompt. The command should read

```
scp REMOTE_USER@REMOTE_ADDR:/remote/file/location /local/file/location
```